# Why does python read my file twice?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a binary file bit by bit because it may be large. My code is:

```
import bz2

read_buffer_size = 10000

with open(r'C:\Python27\python.exe', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read(read_buffer_size)
    while data:
        print len(data)
        data = f.read(read_buffer_size)
```

and it gives me output of:
100

```
10000
10000
8160
10000
10000
8160
```

In this case the file is 28160 bytes, so I was expecting to see:

```
10000
10000
8160
```

Why is python reading my file twice?

Comment: What happens if you put a `print 'starting'` above the `with` ?

Comment: @DavidG, what part is reading it twice? I expect it to read 10000 bytes, then 1000 bytes, then the remaining 8160 bytes. After that, the while loop should exit, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MartinEvans, if I put `print 'starting'` above `with`, it also prints that twice! It's like my whole script is running twice!

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: I'm running the script in idle and also from cmd.exe. I just noticed that the problem seems to be caused by a line I removed from the question because I though it was irrelevant. I've also got `import bz2` at the top of my script. Removing that causes it to only run once!

Comment: It looks like an issue with my systems specifically. I'm turning it off and back on again to see whether that fixes it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that my script was called bz2.py so the import at the start was causing it to import itself, which caused it to run once when it was imported, then again when the rest of it ran.